Combining two dataframes indexed on date based (matching month and year only)
Ignore the date column we just need to merge based on YYYY-MM .
First table has one rwo for each month but second table may have multiple rows for each month. First rows matching month's data should be merged to all of them.
data-frame 1:
2020-01-01   1.480
2020-02-01   1.620
2020-03-01   1.000
2020-04-01   1.000
2020-05-01   1.950
2020-06-01   1.080
2020-07-01   1.480
2020-08-01   1.620
2020-09-01   1.000
2020-10-01   1.000
2020-11-01   1.950
2020-12-01   1.080
2021-01-01   11.480
2021-02-01   12.620
2021-03-01   13.000
2021-04-01   14.000
2021-05-01   15.950
2021-06-01   16.080
2021-07-01   17.480
2021-08-01   18.620
2021-09-01   19.000
2021-10-01   10.000
2021-11-01   11.950
2021-12-01   12.080
2022-01-01   21.480
2022-02-01   22.620
2022-03-01   23.000
2022-04-01   24.000
2022-05-01   25.950
2022-06-01   26.080
2022-07-01   27.480
2022-08-01   28.620
2022-09-01   29.000
2022-10-01   30.000
2022-11-01   31.950
2022-12-01   32.080
2023-01-01   31.480
2023-02-01   31.620
2023-03-01   32.000
2023-04-01   32.200
2023-05-01   31.950
2023-06-01   32.080
2023-07-01   33.080

data-frame 2:
2020-01-15            NaN             NaN             111               111 
2020-02-25            NaN             333             NaN               204 
2021-02-22            123             NaN             NaN               111 
2023-07-18            NaN             324             111               NaN 
2023-03-15            NaN             NaN             NaN               205  

desired data-frame:
2020-01-15     1.480       NaN             NaN             111               111
2020-02-25     1.620       NaN             333             NaN               204 
2021-02-22     1.620       123             NaN             NaN               111 
2023-07-18     33.080      NaN             324             111               NaN 
2023-03-15     32.000      NaN             NaN             NaN               205  


This looks like a simple merge_asof -> pd.merge_asof(df2, df1, on='Dates'). Use left_on and right_on parameters if the name of the columns are different in both columns

@Triky Note you have to merge based on YYYY-MM not on full YYYY-MM-DD.

In your expected output the value of 2021-02-22 is supposed to be 12.62 and not 1.620. Pl check. Change df1,df2 and other column_names to the respective names you've used.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Shown this to tell you the column name I ve used. Don't uncomment as you have df readily
'''
data1 = {
    'Date': pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', periods=43, freq='M'),
    'Value':[1.480, 1.620, <Fill this if required>
'''


# Shown this to tell you the column name I ve used. Don't uncomment as you have df readily
'''
data2 = {
    'Date': [<Fill this if required>],
    'Col1': [<Fill this if required>],
    'Col2': [<Fill this if required>],
    'Col3': [<Fill this if required>],
    'Col4': [<Fill this if required>]
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
'''

# the code starts here
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])

# get year and month from df2
df2['Year'] = df2['Date'].dt.year
df2['Month'] = df2['Date'].dt.month

# get year and month from df1
df1['Year'] = df1['Date'].dt.year
df1['Month'] = df1['Date'].dt.month

merged = pd.merge(df2, df1[['Year', 'Month', 'Value']], how='left', on=['Year', 'Month'])
merged = merged.rename(columns={'Value': 'Value_df1'})

op = merged[['Date', 'Value_df1', 'Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4']]
op = op.fillna(np.nan)

print(op)


You may consider using Numpy 2.0.

I don't know Numpy 2.0 and the updates.

Assuming this as input:
import pandas as pd

data1 = {
    "Date": pd.date_range("2020-01-01", "2023-07-01", freq="MS"),
    "Value": [
        1.480, 1.620, 1.000, 1.000, 1.950, 1.080, 1.480, 1.620, 1.000, 1.000, 1.950, 1.080,
        11.480, 12.620, 13.000, 14.000, 15.950, 16.080, 17.480, 18.620, 19.000, 10.000, 
        11.950, 12.080, 21.480, 22.620, 23.000, 24.000, 25.950, 26.080, 27.480, 28.620, 
        29.000, 30.000, 31.950, 32.080, 31.480, 31.620, 32.000, 32.200, 31.950, 32.080, 33.080,
    ],
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {
    "Date": pd.to_datetime(["2020-01-15", "2020-02-25", "2021-02-22", "2023-07-18", "2023-03-15"]),
    "Column1": [None, None, 123, None, None],
    "Column2": [None, 333, None, 324, None],
    "Column3": [111, None, None, 111, None],
    "Column4": [111, 204, 111, None, 205],
}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

You can use map and add a new column to df2:
m = df1.set_index(df1["Date"].dt.to_period("M"))["Value"]
df2["Value"] = df2.assign(month=df2["Date"].dt.to_period("M"))["month"].map(m)

Or use merge:
out = (
    df2.assign(m=df2["Date"].dt.to_period("M"))
    .merge(df1.assign(m=df1["Date"].dt.to_period("M")).drop(columns="Date"), on="m")
    .drop(columns="m")
)

Both will result in:
        Date  Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4  Value
0 2020-01-15      NaN      NaN    111.0    111.0   1.48
1 2020-02-25      NaN    333.0      NaN    204.0   1.62
2 2021-02-22    123.0      NaN      NaN    111.0  12.62
3 2023-07-18      NaN    324.0    111.0      NaN  33.08
4 2023-03-15      NaN      NaN      NaN    205.0  32.00

